# New dimmer switch is not operating new led panels

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, dimmer-switch, low-voltage

I bought 4 new led panel lights for my drop ceiling and installed Saturday. I also purchased a 0-10 voltage dimmer switch. Yes the lights are dimmable and the switch is for low voltage. I can turn the lights on and off, but they will not dim. Is this possible a bad driver in the led fixture? I know this considered “dead travel”.

Comment: How have you wired the 0-10V stuff?

Comment: The purple wire and grey wires back to the driver. The load wire into the back of the switch with a ground

Comment: What make and model are the LED driver and the dimmer switch in question?

Comment: Thank you all for your help and input. After getting a new one, it has been determined the driver inside the light was bad.